# Why this type of PySpark isin mapping is not Working

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pyspark

Here's my code

```
listOTHERS_hpos = ['BLACKBERRY 7', 'SYMBIAN', 'NOKIA OS', 'BLACKBERRY 10', 'WINDOWS']
lastvalue_month = lastvalue_month.withColumn('handset_type', 
                        when(col('handset_os').isin(listOTHERS_hpos) , lit('OTHERS')))
lastvalue_month.groupBy('handset_os').count().orderBy('count').show()
```

Here's the Output

```
+-------------+-----+
|   handset_os|count|
+-------------+-----+
|      WINDOWS|    6|
|BLACKBERRY 10|    8|
|     NOKIA OS|   15|
|      SYMBIAN|   39|
| BLACKBERRY 7|   43|
|    UNDEFINED| 1218|
|    APPLE IOS| 1496|
|        OTHER| 3705|
|      ANDROID|13218|
+-------------+-----+
```

As by code it should be

```
+-------------+-----+
|   handset_os|count|
+-------------+-----+
|       OTHERS|  111|
|    UNDEFINED| 1218|
|    APPLE IOS| 1496|
|        OTHER| 3705|
|      ANDROID|13218|
+-------------+-----+
```

Comment: Would you mind sharing the DataFrame?

Comment: Sorry, It's not its in hdfs. Just share your hypotesis in answer

Comment: Did you cleaned leading and trailing white spaces? Actually, I have used it and it is working for me. [Check here](https://github.com/Evergreenies/data_engineering_pyspark/blob/main/pyspark_scripts/loan_stat_2018q4.ipynb)

Comment: I think you grouped the data by the wrong column, the new column you created is `handset_type`  not `handset_os`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should group columns using a correct column. Moreover using `.otherwise()` is helpfull in `when`:

```
lastvalue_month = lastvalue_month.withColumn('handset_type', 
                        when(col('handset_os').isin(listOTHERS_hpos) , lit('OTHERS')).otherwise(col('handset_type')))
lastvalue_month.groupBy('handset_type').count().orderBy('count').show()
```